# How to determine what user was used to start Apache Tomcat last (or last few times)

Tags: users, audit, tomcat

On a Mac, or a Linux Tomcat install, how do I determine what user was used last to start Tomcat? Is there information in the logs somewhere to that effect?

Assume that startup.sh and shutdown.sh are being used to control Tomcat.  My best guess is the user(s) who have write access to Catalina.out are the most plausible suspects, but I wanted a hard and fast rule for determining who it is.  Also it isn't currently running so don't say `ps -ef|grep -i Tomcat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the ownership of the PID file, that's a dead giveaway.

Answer (score 2):

Can you:

- check your system's audit log to see which user ran `startup.sh` or `shutdown.sh`?
- check who owns the log file for each timestamped `Catalina.out` (if so configured)?

Comment: auditd is not auditing at that level by default is it?  Also, what if the Catalina ownership looks like `rwxrwx--- root appserver`?  That is similar to what it looked like and I couldnt tell if that means they were using root or appserver, thus this question was asked.  Granted I consider this server to be a bit misconfigured , but that is a different story.

Comment: The default `auditd` configuration is *entirely* dependent on the distribution you're running, we can't tell anything beyond "Linux".  I would suggest experimenting with your own particular installation to determine the answer.